# Kibana 4 visuliazation web cache

Tags: iframe, kibana-4, http-caching

I need to place a Kibana visualization on a highly used webpage. The iframe links from Kibana works great and I have no issuing putting the iframe within the page.  The page displays correctly on the page and looks great. But every user in the company who accesses this page is requesting a new ES query and and it takes several seconds to render the graph.  The data behind the visualization is only updated every 5 minutes.

How can I make an image cache of the Kibana visualization?  The image cache only needs to update one every 5 minutes.  Everybody who accesses the page with the Kebana graph should access the web cache image so it renders faster, and puts less strain on my ES cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it would be nice.  It was requested [a while back](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1366).